# How do i edit Values in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, memory-address

I am making a Visual Basic 2008 application, and want to be able to change the value at a particular memory address. For example, I want to change the value at Memory Address `0xB7CE50` to `100000`. Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What language are you using?

Comment: Visual basic i am making a application to edit money in a game...

Comment: Ok now i am using Visual studio 2008 on C# trying to edit the memory of this address (0xB7CE50) to value 100000 is there a function to write these options to a game im not sure how i can be more clear

Comment: What do you think is at that address?

Comment: @Cody have you looked at a program called ArtMoney? http://www.artmoney.ru/

Answer (score 2):

I believe Cody Beer is running a game and looking for a program such as HxD or something similar which will allow him to edit the main memory so he can change the amount of money he has in-game to the maximum amount.  VS is the wrong tool for this.

Comment: I agree. He needs something to act as a debugger and to permit him to inspect and modify the address space of another program. He should either get a program someone else has written, or should improve his skill with the game so he doesn't have to cheat.

Answer (score 1):

You typically just use the debugger, and place the variable you're looking to change in the Watch window, then just type in the new value.

---

It appears that you want a way for a .NET program to modify a particular memory address of another program.

There is no way to do this with .NET as far as I know, and there's only barely a way to do this outside of .NET. As I suggested, you could do this with a debugger. In order to do it from a program, your program will have to be a debugger!

The good news is that this is possible. See [Visual Studio Debugger Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb161718.aspx). Do not be put off by the fact that it seems to require Visual Studio. What you may not know is that it's possible to create a program, based on Visual Studio, that looks and behaves entirely like a stand-alone executable.

I believe there are also ways to "be a debugger" by using APIs described in the Windows SDK, but I don't know where the documentation for them is.

Comment: I do not think this answer directly applies to the original question's intended meaning.

Comment: i am just looking for something like a function do i have to use C# for this?

Comment: @Nathan: I'm not sure I know what the intended meaning is, in that case.

Comment: @Cody: what are you attempting to accomplish? What is that address? Is the address always the same address?

Comment: im trying to increase a value which will increase my IN-Game money the address is 0xB7CE50 and yes it is always the same address and the value 100000

Comment: @Cody: what kind of program is this? C++? Why is that address always the same?

Comment: well its like on a singleplayer game when you put in a cheat for example cars fly it sets a address's value as 1 instead of 0 (basicly) and this is C#

Comment: @John I don't know if you've ever heard of a program called ArtMoney, but it has a similar intent. Cody is trying to access raw system memory addresses so that he can change a value (like player gold) on command.

Comment: @Nathan: I'm not getting how he arranges for the same data to be at the same address. This isn't a real-mode DOS program, is it?

Comment: @John I'm not terribly familiar with the underpinnings of how it works, but I guess the memory addresses used by the target application (game) are constant; so long as you know the physical address and it isn't going to change it is technically possible to alter the value at that address externally.

Comment: @Nathan: @Cody: I think some context is needed here. Normal .NET programs don't work this way. Is this some XBox game or something?

Comment: @John I apologize if that wasn't clear, but he's not targeting the .NET program's memory addresses, rather he wants to create a program in .NET to directly modify memory addresses set by another application (most likely a game).

Comment: @Cody: if this is true, then please update your question to say so. There is no way I could guess this! @Nathan: thanks for the "requirements gathering" exercise.

Comment: @John My pleasure! it only took about 13 comments :p

Answer (score 0):

Its easy by GUI operation.

1. open the one of four Memory Views from Debug -> Windows -> Memory 1-4
2. keyin the correct address on address filed.
3. change the value at the right address.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a memory editor software like TSearch etc...
not sure if that is possible with VS.